# Jquery, keeping subnav open after click until new hover

Tags: jquery

I'm using a menu to load a  (so no way to check the url) and I'd like to keep the submenu open after a click on a link and until a new hover on the main bar.

JS :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$("ul#topnav li").hover(function() { //Hover over event on list item
    $(this).css({ 'background' : '#32CD32 '}); //Add background color + image on hovered list item
    $(this).find("span").show(); //Show the subnav

});
} , function() { //on hover out...
    $(this).css({ 'background' : 'none'}); //Ditch the background
    $(this).find("span").hide(); //Hide the subnav
});
```

HTML :

```
<ul id="topnav">

        <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>

        <li>
            <a href="test.php">Test</a>
            <span class="menud">
                <a href="test2.php">Test2</a> |
                <a href="">.</a> |
                <a href="">.</a>
            </span>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

CSS :

```
 ul#topnav {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width:100%;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #000000;

}

ul#topnav li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #32CD32;
}
ul#topnav li a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#topnav li a:hover{ color: #000000; font-weight:bold;cursor:default;}
ul#topnav li:hover { background: #32CD32 ; }
ul#topnav li span.menud {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top:30px;
    display: none;
    width:100%;
    background: #32CD32;
    color: #fff;
}

ul#topnav li:hover span.menud { display: block; width:100%;}
ul#topnav li span.menud a { display: inline; }
ul#topnav li span.menud a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

Please forgive me, I'm not a native english speaker and thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this a single-page website / app?

Comment: (I'm not sure to understand the question :p)
Single page for the user.
Many "real" pages all called in the same <div> with jquery (another js file)

Comment: Single-page as in - it doesn't need to load again (as loading a different page would loose all of your hover states).

This may be what is happening to your page / menu.

I have a better solution for your hovering code though. Please see my answer. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/femMf/)**

This wont necessarily fix your issue (as my comment explains) but it does improve the hovering, which may have been your issue in the first place. :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("ul#topnav li").bind('mouseover', function() { //Hover over event on list item
    $(this).css({ 'background' : '#32CD32 '}); //Add background color + image on hovered list item
    $(this).find("span").show(); //Show the subnav

}).bind('mouseout', function() { //on hover out...
    $(this).css({ 'background' : 'none'}); //Ditch the background
    $(this).find("span").hide(); //Hide the subnav
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look a bind(). Maybe there's a way to "pause" jquery (delay doesn't seem to do the trick).